# Is it correct to say, " could you set down the massage bill to my room"?

Tags: meaning

Is it correct to ask " could you set down the massage bill to my room"?

Answer (score 1):

[Set down](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/set--down) normally means to put aside for later and doesn't really work in this context.

Instead, if you want to send a copy of the bill to your room, you could use:

> Could you send the massage bill to my room?

If, however you want to add the charge of the massage to your room bill, then you could use:

> Could you charge the massage to my room?